# FileNotFoundError: No such File due to Google Colab TimeOut? Upgrading to CoLab Pro or switching to AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-colaboratory, file-not-found, nosuchfileexception

I am training a model on Colab and every time I am trying to use Colab's GPU, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-f43ade94ee10> in <module>()
      5                     epochs = 10,
      6                     use_multiprocessing=True,
----> 7                     workers=2)

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/request.py in _parse_uri(self, uri)
    271                 # Reading: check that the file exists (but is allowed a dir)
    272                 if not os.path.exists(fn):
--> 273                     raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
    274             else:
    275                 # Writing: check that the directory to write to does exist

FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/s01_l01/1_1.png'
```

Could this be due to a Google Drive Timeout?

I am now thinking about upgrading to Colab Pro and I am wondering if it is worth it? Or is it maybe worth to switching to AWS? And if a switch to AWS is worth it, is there a limit regarding the runtime as it is in CoLab (free version: 12 hours, Pro: 24 hours)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this link for avoiding timeout in google colab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my question. I used function `ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Connect pushed"); 
    document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);` If yoiu want, you can also answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468830/filenotfounderror-no-such-file-error-occuring-due-to-timeout-of-google-driv. It's a bountied question of myself.